# Create dictionary from multiple lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from multiple lists,based on the index of the word in the list. They key will be the word itself and the key will be index of the word
in the list. If the word appears twice then the value be like [postiion1, position2].
In the following example. 2nd list has the twice so for 'the' it will be 'the':[2,6]
etc.

```
def create_myDict(mylists):       
    myDic = {}
    for t in mylists:
        myDic[t[0]] = t[:]
    return myDic
```

**Sample Input:**

```
[['why', 'did', 'the', 'dalmation', 'need', 'glasses', 'he', 'was', 'seeing', 'spots']
,['what', 'did', 'the', 'book', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'page', 'don', 't', 'turn', 'away', 'from', 'me']]
```

**Expected output:**

```
myDic ={ 'what':[0], 'did':[1], 'the':[2,6],
'book':[3],'say':[4],'to':[5],'page':[7],'don':[8]
.....
}
```

But it's not working. Any Ideas.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Dictionary is a set of named elements, each name being unique. It is not obvious what you really want to create out of a list of words - what are your keys, what are your values?

Comment: I see two problems with the spec right away: 1) if you have a dictionary whose keys are the first (or really any) element of the list, whose values are the list itself, then two lists with the same first element will overwrite each other as values in the dictionary. 2) a dictionary does not preserve order at all. So really, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to map the word to it's position in the list. So basically the word will be key and the value will be index/it's position in the list for the first case. For second case it's just the number of times that occurs in the list.

Comment: dicts can not have duplicate keys.... so you have to remove duplicates ...

Comment: Ok I updated the question. I am passing multiple lists and want to create a dictionary from them. So the word will be key and the value will be it's occurrence/position in the list.

Comment: "the word will be key" - it won't work because words are not unique while the keys in a dictionary should be unique. You might try to clarify what is the purpose of this, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: will the value of `the` be `[2,6]` in `myDic`?

Comment: Correct. I updated it.

Comment: The word "the" occurs three times, once in list1 and twice in list2. Are you sure you want the output to just be `[2, 6]`?

Comment: @martineau you are right. What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps something like `[2, [2, 6]]`. Also, don't you want `'don\'t',` in list2 rather than `'don', 't',`?

Comment: @martineau I really don't my question to be closed. I am trying to ask the way i can. I parse input text build lists. Now trying to create an index. So if someone search for the text, i return it.
http://pastebin.com/JP7mqHf5 . The dont is fine, as it parsed raw into a word and all the punctuation is already stripped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will create a dictionary with words as keys and lists of their indices as values:

```
def create_myDict(mylists):
    myDict = {}
    for sublist in mylists: 
        for i in range(len(sublist)):
            if sublist[i] in myDict:
               myDict[sublist[i]].append(i)
            else:
               myDict[sublist[i]] = [i]

    return myDict
```

Same thing, a bit shorter with `setdefault`:

```
def create_myDict(mylists):
    myDict = {}
    for sublist in mylists: 
        for i in range(len(sublist)):
            myDict.setdefault(sublist[i], []).append(i)
    return myDict
```

There's also `collections.defaultdict` if you don't want to bother with checking the key existence at all:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def create_myDict(mylists):
    myDict = defaultdict(list)
    for sublist in mylists: 
        for i in range(len(sublist)):
            myDict[sublist[i]].append(i)
    return myDict
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting this error. 
if mylist[i] in myDict:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @jamesT You are getting this error when? Can you print `mylist` and make sure it is a list of strings?

Comment: It is indeed string. the list i am getting is somewhat like this. [['what', 'did'],['why', 'did', 'the', 'strawberry']] –

Comment: @jamesT This is not how your "sample input" looks. You are doing something wrong in pre-processing. Try to enter your sample input and you'll get the right result.

Comment: i updated my sample input in the question. Sorry about it. I am parsing text and getting a list which it seems has sublists etc.

Comment: @jamesT The question doesn't make sense any more, because you have list of lists. Which indices do you want to store? Of a word within a sublist? Do you want to flatten list of lists into a list and then get indices? Update your sample output accordingly. I.e., 'did' is present in both lists, what is the expected output? Same for 'what' - it is only in the second list - what do you expect it to match?

Comment: I parse text from a file and it creates this structure. What i want is to create a dictionary out of this nested list. See here, What i am trying to do is something like this.
http://pastebin.com/AySwVD3M
Let me know if that clarifies your comment?

Comment: @jamesT So, you basically need a summary of word positions in a list? You realize it will not be reversible, i.e., you never know from which list a particular word has come from, only the position of it in some list.

Comment: You are right, just the summary  and it would be some what similar to the snippet i showed you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is getting closer to what i want. The issue is if i try to search it back like 
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AySwVD3M
I am not getting the correct sublist/result back. For example if i search for 'to', which is mapped like this:
'to': [2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 12, 5, 7, 9, 9, 5, 9, 11, 5, 6, 5, 5, 8, 5]
I get back somewhat like this.
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CvLe1v6A
Any suggestions?

Comment: @jamesT Sorry, but this deviates from the original question too much please post another one. I can't co-author your project - you keep adding things which were not there originally. Your last comment is not clear. I just said that with such mapping you won't be able to find word in a particular list because you don't store the number of the list, only the number of a word in one of the lists. You probably don't want a dictionary at all, so far I can say... An answer by martineau is something I'd consider to be the solution for your problem at least for now.

Comment: @jamesT: My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21419839/355230), which is a bit longer, addresses the issue of not knowing which list the word was found in by producing an entry -- either a sublist of indices or the value `None` -- for all the words in the input lists. The order of these entries corresponds to the order of the input lists.

Answer (score 2):

I think this'll do what you need. The length of the list for each word is the same and will either contain`None`or a list of indices for each of the corresponding lists:

```
import collections

def create_myDict(*lists):
    """ Map words to their index positions in each of the lists. """
    # initialize results
    unique_words = {word for words in lists for word in words}
    results = {word: [[] for _ in xrange(len(lists))] for word in unique_words}

    for list_num, words in enumerate(lists):
        indices = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            indices[word].append(index)
        for word in indices:
            results[word][list_num] = indices[word]

    # return results with empty lists converted to None
    return {word: [None if not index else index for index in indicies]
                for word, indicies in results.iteritems()}

list1 = ['why', 'did', 'the', 'dalmation', 'need', 'glasses', 'he', 'was',
         'seeing', 'spots']
list2 = ['what', 'did', 'the', 'book', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'page', 'don\'t',
         'turn', 'away', 'from', 'me']

print 'create_myDict(list1, list2) = {'
for item in sorted(create_myDict(list1, list2).items()):
    print '    {!r}: {},'.format(*item)
print '}'
```

Output from sample lists:

```
create_myDict(list1, list2) = {
    'away': [None, [10]],    
    'book': [None, [3]],     
    'dalmation': [[3], None],
    'did': [[1], [1]],       
    "don't": [None, [8]],    
    'from': [None, [11]],    
    'glasses': [[5], None],  
    'he': [[6], None],       
    'me': [None, [12]],      
    'need': [[4], None],     
    'page': [None, [7]],     
    'say': [None, [4]],      
    'seeing': [[8], None],   
    'spots': [[9], None],    
    'the': [[2], [2, 6]],    
    'to': [None, [5]],       
    'turn': [None, [9]],     
    'was': [[7], None],      
    'what': [None, [0]],     
    'why': [[0], None],      
}
```

**Update**

If your input is a list of list, as you mentioned in a comment, just do something like this:

```
myinput = [['what', 'did'], ['why', 'did', 'the', 'strawberry']]

print 'create_myDict(*myinput) = {'
for item in sorted(create_myDict(*myinput).items()):
    print '    {!r}: {},'.format(*item)
print '}'
```

Output:

```
create_myDict(*myinput) = {
    'did': [[1], [1]],
    'strawberry': [None, [3]],
    'the': [None, [2]],
    'what': [[0], None],
    'why': [None, [0]],
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just printed my input and it looks like it's a nested list like this. So the solution you proposed might not work.
[['what', 'did'],['why', 'did', 'the', 'strawberry']]

Comment: If your input is a list of lists like that, you can just call `create_myDict(*myinput)`.

Comment: I am getting this error.
    unique_words = {word for words in lists for word in words}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: That error's because you changed it in the `print 'create_myDict(*myinput) ='` line but not in the actual call in the function in line `for item in sorted(create_myDict(*myinput).items()):`. See my update.

Answer (score -1):

maybe

```
my_word_list = ['why', 'did', 'the', 'dalmation', 'need', 'glasses', 'he', 'was', 'seeing', 'spots']
order_occurance = dict(zip(my_word_list,xrange(1000000000)))

from collections import Counter
count_occurance = Counter(my_word_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

This code should work:

```
def cd(mylists):
    myDic = {}
    for t in mylists:
        if t in myDic.keys():
            myDic[t]+=1
        else:
            myDic[t]=1
    return myDic
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this error. 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Sorting the lists loses the original word indices.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor that was what he originally wanted before editing the code. I just changed some code in for loop.
Anyway, there was no need of sorting there, edited.